# Observable refresh only first time

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a observable property  (named properties) in my object. Unfortunately, it refreshes  only when I change it first time.

What can be wrong?

**Code:**

```
var Session = function(vm, session) {
var self = this;
ko.mapping.fromJS(session, {}, self);

self.selectedSessionProperty = ko.observable('');

self.restarting = ko.observable(false);

if (! ko.isObservable(self.properties)) {
  self.properties = ko.observableArray();
}

self.availableNewProperties = ko.computed(function() {
  var addedIndex = {};
  $.each(self.properties(), function(index, property) {
    addedIndex[property.key] = true;
  });
  var result = $.grep(vm.availableSessionProperties(), function(property) {
    return ! addedIndex[property.name];
  });
  return result;
});
};
```

Comment: Are doing a conditional initialization of the _properties_ var? I don't know what I am missing but i do not see modifications of the var. Could you add more info or an external snippet?

Comment: I need ask in a little another way - how to know which function change observable array?

Answer (score 1):

try self.properties.valueHasMutated(); after your loop, this should trigger knockout to update.

You can also use the knockout utility functions to help you with arrays: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html